# How to label convergence of simultaneous tasks in PERT chart?

Tags: agile

I am trying to create a PERT chart to show the application of Agile to a certain workflow.

There is a node which diverges into 4 parallel edges/nodes, representing 4 tasks which are completed simultaneously.

The results from all 4 simultaneous tasks are then used in the next step, so 4 edges converge from 4 nodes into 1 node, which represents the next task/milestone.

However, since there are 4 edges coverging to 1 node, it's unclear to me as to how to label it. There's only 1 task being done in that next step, but I have 4 edges and each edge is supposed to be labeled.

Should I write the same thing 4 times? or only label 1 of the 4 edges?

Comment: Are you using the "activity on node" or "activity on arrow" convention?

Comment: @EuanM  They taught us activities go on the edges (arrows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `each edge is supposed to be labeled` is not a rule carved in stone. Some use the merging node as the label.

Alternatively, you could label each of the 4 edges as ***integration*** or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

With "Activity on Arrow", there should only be one node from which the four arrows are spawned, and then only one further node at which all four arrows terminate.

Please note:

1. Arrows do not need to be a single straight line.
2. Each arrow represents an activity - so if there are four activities, you need only have four arrows.
3. It sounds like you were thinking of having four separate dummy nodes, one at the end of each actual activity, each of which would then have a dummy activity arrow leading to the actual node at the termination of the four parallel activities.

These are unnecessary, as a) they're serving no logical purpose in the PERT network and b) the diagrammatic purpose they serve can be better carried out by having each of the non-dummy arrows made out of three straight lines: four lines that fan out from the first node; then four parallel lines; then four lines that converge on the second node.

You would then label the four parallel sections of the arrows with the four activity descriptions.

Comment: There was only one node from which the 4 edges originated and terminated. There were no dummy nodes. The question was how to label the 4 edges when converging because there are no longer 4 separate tasks (there were when they originated). There was only 1 task during convergence. I ended up labeling all 4 converging edges the same but only putting the story point for the task on one of them.

Comment: I'm now unsure how the part in the OQ stating "so 4 edges converge from 4 nodes into 1 node" fits in.